# How to "save" string variable from settings menu

Tags: java, android

I'm new about coding so i'm sorry for my "basic" questions.

I'm coding an Android app with Android studio; very simple, only webview that show my website but i need to have in settings menu an editText where i can modify my website url.

I made two activitys(Main and Settings) that i post; Could anyone help me to understand how can i store permanently the url that i write in my editText in order to open that url when i came back to main activity?
Hope i submit clearly my question!!
Thanks in advance

```
Settings.java
private EditText editsite;
    private Button button;
    public static TextView actSite;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        editsite = findViewById(R.id.editsite);
        button = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        actSite = findViewById(R.id.actSite);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            String strData = editsite.getText().toString();
            if (strData.length()<=0) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Sito non valido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                actSite.setText(strData);
```

```
Main Activity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        WebView vista = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.vista);

        vista.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        vista.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


       vista.loadUrl("www.google.com");  //examplesite

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: To be honest... I'm so confused. Are you trying to make a tipical "search input"? Why do you need two activities for that? If you want to store persistent data you can use `sharedPreferences`

Comment: No it isn't a "search input"!! I'va main activity where i'll show my demostration site with only webview and setting activity with editText where i'll switch from website to other as needed.
It's wrong strategy for my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). And everytime the MainActivity starts you load the Shared Preferences and get the String.
Example:
set Shared Preferences

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();  
 editor.putString("URL", "Your url");
editor.apply();
```

Get the value

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String url= prefs.getString("URL", "String if URL is emtpy");
```